# FormView Insert Mode: e.Values not filled, except when it is

Tags: asp.net, formview

The same web project behaves differently under Framework 2.0 and Framework 4.0. When the ItemInserting event fires, e.Values is empty when the site runs on IIS with Framework 2.0.

When the ItemInserting event fires with the site hosted in VS 2010 using Framework 4, then e.Values is perfect.

Any thoughts?

Bill

Cincinnati, OH

Comment: Is the markup different in any way?  Are you binding to a DataSource control?

Comment: It may have been a bug fix logged through connect.microsoft.com, and that's why it works in 4.0..... is 2.0 out of warranty yet?

Answer (score 1):

The server was upgrade to Framework 4 and it all works now, with no code changes.

I did some research online, there is a 'feature' in Framework 2 that causes this behavior.